# Is it possible to remove a shape that is in the same layer as another shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shapes, selections

I created two shapes in the same layer by mistake and I want to delete one of them only. I couldn't go back with ctrl z because I already did several other stuff afterwards.

Is it possible to remove one shape from a layer that contains another shape which I want to keep? I am using Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: What is the nature of the "shapes"? Shape layers? Vector layers? Pixel Layers?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

1. Switch to the Path panel
2. Duplicate the path
3. Use the Direct Selection tool to select the shape you want to delete, this may be one segment or point at a time, and delete that shape or any part of it

Is this what you are asking for?